# Localization of In-App Purchase confirmation dialog

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I've implemented iAP in my app, but the English confirmation dialog is not very friendly to Chinese users. I tested iAP in sandbox, whatever I changed the system language, the dialog only displayed in English, but the product name was localized.

The dialog text looks like below.

```
Confirm Your In App Purchase
Do you want to buy one [product name in Chinese] for [price in Chinese]?
```

Does anyone know how to localize the rest of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a Test User for the Chinese iTunes Store instead of the US iTunes Store on iTunes Connect and then logging in as that user.